# What's the difference between scoring in RFECV versus GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, rfe

I am trying to run RFECV to select the best features and GridSearchCV to get the best hyperparameters. My code looks like this:

```py
params = {'estimator__C': [1e-4, 1e4]}
estimator = LogisticRegression(random_state=123)
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='recall')
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, params, cv=5)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I include the same scoring metric within GridSearchCV, I get different best features, n_features, and parameters from cv_results. Why is this happening and which of these approaches is correct?

```py
params = {'estimator__C': [1e-4, 1e4]}
estimator = LogisticRegression(random_state=123)
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='recall')
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, params, cv=5, scoring='recall')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a personal policy of not upvoting answers to your questions?

Comment: @desertnaut nope, just didn’t know that was important to people. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Thanks. Voting is central to the whole SO model - you may want to have a quick look at [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening

In the second case, where you don't specify explicitly the `scoring`, `GridSearchCV` will use the default scoring of the estimator used, here `LogisticRegression`; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> **scoring : *string, callable, list/tuple, dict or None, default: None***
>
> [...]
>
> If None, the estimator’s score method is used.

And what is that score for `LogisticRegression`? Again from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score):

> **score** *(self, X, y, sample_weight=None)*
>
> Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.

So, in the first case, for the `GridSearchCV` part, you get the parameters that maximize the *accuracy*, while in the second one the ones that maximize the *recall*. In principle, the parameters that maximize these two different metrics need not be the same (they *can* be, of course, but they can very well *not* be, as here).

> which of these approaches is correct?

Technically speaking, both approaches are correct; the only one that can answer that question is yourself, and it has to do with what metric is preferable for your *business* problem.

That said, the first approach admittedly looks kind of weird - why you would want to optimize for two *different* metrics during `RFECV` and `GridSearchCV`? At least in principle, it would make much more sense to optimize everything according to your chosen metric.

Again, keep in mind that all these techniques are actually *ad hoc* approaches, without much theory behind them; the ultimate judge is the experiment. So, if you are interested, say, in maximizing the accuracy of your final model, but you find out that an intermediate `RFECV` stage which tries to maximize recall gives a better overall accuracy at the end, you might very well just go for it...